# How to track attempted data recovery

Tags: data-recovery

I gave my external hard disk to one of my (not so close) friends to copy movies from it. He had it for a day. I know I am being paranoid, but is there a way for Linux to check if he attempted data recovery on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way for Linux to check if he attempted data recovery on it ?

Absolutely not, *assuming he did a good job.* Serious data recovery procedures explicitly require that the source drive **be not altered in any way** to ensure data does not get overwritten.

If the drive showed signs of usage, that would mean he didn't do a very good job.